# Is titling a question "(SEMI-INTERACTIVE PUZZLE) The Actual Title" really what we should be doing?

Tags: discussion

It seems like this is adding the sort of information one would expect in a tag into the title. And not subtly either. As screaming capital letters right at the beginning of the title this seems like the wrong way to label a question.

As a [tag now exists](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semi-interactive-puzzle) for such puzzles I'm suggesting we don't need to title puzzles in this way.

Examples:

[Treasure hunt 'round the world! (prologue)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16551/semi-interactive-puzzle-treasure-hunt-round-the-world)

[You're invited! Now what?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16474/semi-interactive-puzzle-youre-invited-now-what)

Comment: I would agree to this. It seems rather unnecessary to include a Tag into the title as that is one of the purposes of a tag (let alone in all capitals). I once use to include "Riddle:" into my riddle titles (as I was new) however after suggestions I now no longer include it. (However I still have questions with "Riddle:" in them which have not been edited so....I think this should be discussed further)

Comment: i know what you mean. I doubt my puzzle have perfect titles and I'm not saying a riddle with the word `riddle` in the title is bad, but the title of these examples make me feel bad.

Comment: I think it's also the fact that the 'real' title is smaller than the tag, and is also after it (making it seem very insignificant) - which is defeating its own purpose.

Comment: I think you're probably right, but I'd like to hear it from someone official before I make a change - I was simply copying the format of the question previous to mine. :) I do think it's important to note when a puzzle is semi-interactive, because they will be treated differently than other puzzles, but the big link at the top of the question itself should suffice.

Comment: Based on xnor and his fabulous Meta.SE link, the titles of the linked questions have been changed - rest assured, they did used to look just as obnoxious as they do in the links on this question.

Comment: Oh No.... What have I done.... Hold on someone beat me to posting an interactive puzzle? What???? I'm not even 30% done the one I'm writing...  i do hope I haven't started a trend of bad puzzles showing up before mine gets posted ._. //continues mumbling to self...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quoting from [this meta SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/275609):

- It is completely unnecessary to force tags into your question titles.
- The only time you should use tags in your title is when *they are organic to the conversational tone of the title*.

I find "(SEMI INTERACTIVE PUZZLE)" distracting and tacked on, even if it weren't all caps. So, I think it should be removed (preferred) or incorporated into the title as "A semi-interactive puzzle about ...".

But, most titles that mention a tag like "riddle" do so unobtrusively, and naming the type of puzzle is vital to describing it, so that's OK.